# Marker component is not added to the DOM in the initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Am using `Marker` components for custom markup for markers.

```
<Map
 onStyleLoad={this.onStyleLoad}
 style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
 containerStyle={{
 height: "100%",
 width: "100%"
}}
fitBounds={this.getBounds(markerPoints)}>
 <Marker><img .../> </Marker>
 <Marker><img .../> </Marker>
</Map>
```

`Marker` component is not added to the DOM until i resize the browser or any action like Zoom or Pan (any action inside the map). is it a known issue? if so whats the workaround for this?

Comment: You could try to invoke resize on pageload, if nothing else works: `window.onresize();`

Comment: have used `onStyleLoad` to get the `map` object. Unfortunately this callback didn't triggered in such situations. Without `map` object can't use any mapbox api's in `resize` or any other life cycle methods of react component.